# Google AJAX API loader returning null

Tags: ajax, api, loader

We have been using google AJAX API loader (to get the location of a client based on her IP) as described here:

code.google.com/apis/ajax/documentation/#ClientLocation

Earlier when the API loader was included in any file
then
it used to populate the google.loader.ClientLocation property with data about the client

but two days back i found that it is returning null.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well.. the reason i found is that the API is not able to resolve my IP. I don't know why...
I found it to be working fine with other IPs.